# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 image upload issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http-headers

I can't seem to upload an image. I'm getting `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` as an error for a POST request.  I can't find where the parsing/JSON issue is, but when I remove the image request/response/model field, the POST works well.

```
try { 
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('email', formState.inputs.email.value);
  formData.append('image', formState.inputs.image.value);
  const responseData = await sendRequest(
    'http://localhost:3001/api/users/signup',
    'POST',
    formData,
  );
  auth.login(responseData.userId, responseData.token);
} catch (err) { }
```

On the back end: 
user-routes.js

```
const fileUpload = require('../middleware/file-upload');
router.post('/signup',
  fileUpload.single('image'),
```

file-upload.js

```
const multer = require('multer');
const uuid = require('uuid/v1');

const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
    'image/png': 'png',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
    'image/jpg': 'jpg'
};

const fileUpload = multer({
    limits: 5000000,
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, 'uploads/images');
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
            const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
            cb(null, uuid() + '.' + ext);
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const isValid = !!MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        let error = isValid ? null : new Error('Invalid mime type!');
        cb(error, isValid);
    }
});

module.exports = fileUpload;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const usersRoutes = require('./routes/users-routes');
const HttpError = require('./models/http-error');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use('/uploads/images', express.static(path.join('uploads', 'images')));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
    next();
});

app.use('/api/users', usersRoutes);
```

What have I missed? The only JSON data I'm parsing is the userId and email in local storage.

Comment: The `<` in your JSON is probably from sending HTML instead of JSON, which can be caused by encountering a 500 error. Are you seeing any error messages from your server?

Comment: So i added  a line to see the error because not registering as a 500 error. res.status(error.code || 500);
    res.status(err.status >= 100 && err.status < 600 ? err.code : 500).send(err.message);
    res.json({ message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred!' });
});  Yeah, I'm just trying to figure out where the HTML is coming from because the Request header content type is multi-part/formdata. THe response is text/html. Thanks. :)

Comment: Before I added that line, I was getting `RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: ENOENT`.

Comment: Often you won't be able to check for a 500 error in that way because they can come from your server throwing an error. If you look in the console for your server do you see any error messages (like stack traces)?

Comment: @HenryWoody I'm getting `layer.handle_error` `trim_prefix` and  `Function.process_params` in the trace Console is registering a 500 error.

Comment: Ah that's helpful, can you edit the question to include the full error message / stack trace?

Comment: `ReferenceError: err is not defined
    at C:\Users\nnmot\Desktop\jobapp\api\server.js:63:16
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\nnmot\Desktop\jobapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\nnmot\Desktop\jobapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\nnmot\Desktop\jobapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\nnmot\Desktop\jobapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\nnmot\Desktop\jobapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
`

Comment: `users-controllers.js` cuz I should have posted that, too.  `const {email} = req.body;     const createdUser = new User({
        email,
        //image: req.file.path,
      
    });`

Comment: Could be caused by the update you made (mentioned in your first comment). If you remove that what error do you get?

Comment: not likely. `RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: ENOENT
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:241:11)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:232:8)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:607:9)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:717:5)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\nnmot\Desktop\jobapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\nnmot\Desktop\jobapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)` It's got to be about the response data

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your server.js file

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```